# Is it possible to use adjustPan and keep the selection action mode on screen?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext, android-actionbar, adjustpan

I have an EditText element at the bottom of the screen (like Whatsapp i.e), and I'm using android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" in order not to hide the EditText when the keyboard appears. It works fine, it pushes the whole layout up so that the EditText can be seen.

Now, the problem is that when I select the text, the action mode bar doesn't appear, as if it was pushed up along with the layout.

I'm not using an explicit action bar in my layout, it's the one that appears on pre M devices when a text selection is made.

The layout hierarchy goes like this:

```
<FrameLayout>
 <GLSurfaceView/>
 <EditText/>
</FrameLayout>
```

So all I want to do is this action mode to keep it's position even when the keyboard is opened, using the pan behaviour.

adjustResize doesn't work for me. When set, the keyboard is over the EditText, and nothing resizes, probably due to GLSurfaceView.

Thanks!